# When I upload image to Firebase Storage, an extra image appears. Swift 4, Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

I have not seen this problem or issue raised anywhere else online.

When I upload an image(s) to Firebase Storage, one extra duplicate image appears. i.e If I upload 1 image, 2 will appear in the Storage (if I upload 3, 4 will appear), it looks like this:
[image: Duplicate image]

I have a takePicture ViewController where I handle the actual image taking and here is my upload to Firebase Storage class code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class ImageUploadManager: NSObject {

    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let postImage = takePicViewController().postImage
    let images = takePicViewController().images


    //Start of send to storage fuction
    func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, postNumber: Int, progressBlock: @escaping (_ percentage: Double) -> Void, completionBlock: @escaping (_ url: String?, _ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("post\(takePicViewController().finalPost + postNumber)").child(imageName)

        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) {
            let metadata = storageRef

            let uploadTask = metadata.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

                guard let metadata = metadata else {
                    return
                }

                // You can also access to download URL after upload.
//                storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
//
//                    guard let downloadURL = url else {
//                        return
//                    }
//
//                }
            }

            // For progress
            uploadTask.observe(.progress, handler: { (snapshot) in
                guard let progress = snapshot.progress else {
                    return
                }

                let percentage = (Float(progress.completedUnitCount) / Float(progress.totalUnitCount))
                progressBlock(Double(percentage))
            })

        } else {
            completionBlock(nil, "Image could not be converted to Data.")
        }

    } //End of send to storage function


} //End of ImgUploadClass
```

Also these are my Firebase Storage rules:

```
  service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And also my Firebase Storage is structured as: UID/post(#)/imageName

Lastly, I also upload to Firebase Realtime Database, however that is irrelevant for this problem.

Comment: That code looks ok to me. I would guess you're calling it twice. Also, the *images* and *postImage* vars are unused in that class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this line:

```
let metadata = storageRef
```

is messing up with your code. Can you try changing the constant's name to something else and test it. Your closure's parameter is also called `metadata` and I think it messes it up.

Comment: tried it, didnt i have found other solution though, thanks anyways!